# Mule is throwing error: No namespace on "someElement" element

Tags: mule

I provided snippet of my code that should work normally but it doesn't.

In short, my flow is triggered by quartz, read some data from database, loop through results, on each loop do something and then finish.

Everything works ok when result from service (http outbound) return that there is nothing to give back, but when choice (in flow) is not default it redirect to sub-flow where xslt perform and save file. File saves like it should (I checked with external tools if xml suits criteria) and logger prints out number 3 as proof that it is finished (couple of lines before error is thrown) but after that I get error given below. Anyone knows why? I am out of ideas.

My flow:

```
<flow name="msp2bassGettingContent" doc:name="Starter">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz" jobName="Starter" repeatInterval="600000" startDelay="3000">
        <quartz:event-generator-job groupName="Generator" jobGroupName="Generator">
            <quartz:payload file="${prop.requestEvent}"/>
        </quartz:event-generator-job>
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="getUnreadedRoutes" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="JDBCConnector" doc:name="GetNulls">
        <jdbc:query key="getUnreadedRoutes" value="SELECT routeid FROM kptemp WHERE readed IS NULL"/>
    </jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
    <foreach collection="#[message.payload]" doc:name="For Each" counterVariableName="counter123">
        <flow-ref name="msp2bass" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
    </foreach>
</flow>

<sub-flow name="msp2bass" doc:name="msp2bassGetEvent">
    <set-variable variableName="routeid" value="#[payload['routeid']]" doc:name="Variable"/>
    <set-payload value="<a/>;" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
    <mulexml:xslt-transformer maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" xsl-file="${prop.createRequest}" doc:name="XSLT" ignoreBadInput="true">
        <mulexml:context-property key="customerId" value="${prop.customerId}"/>
        <mulexml:context-property key="siteName" value="${prop.siteName}"/>
        <mulexml:context-property key="routeID" value="#[routeid]"/>
    </mulexml:xslt-transformer>
    <cxf:proxy-client payload="body" doc:name="SOAP">
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <spring:ref bean="WSS4JOutInterceptorBean"/>
        </cxf:outInterceptors>
    </cxf:proxy-client>
    <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${prop.host}" port="${prop.port}" path="${prop.path}" method="POST" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS1" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <byte-array-to-object-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to Object"/>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[xpath('boolean(//soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns2:processComplexResponse/MSPResponse/serviceEvents/measurements/name)')]">
            <flow-ref name="transform" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <logger message="Not null: #[routeid]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</sub-flow>

<sub-flow name="transform" doc:name="transform">
    <logger message="Payload: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <mulexml:xslt-transformer maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" xsl-file="${prop.transformer}" doc:name="XSLT"/>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="./work" outputPattern="#[routeid].xml" responseTimeout="10000" disableTransportTransformer="true" doc:name="File"/>
    <logger message="3" level="INFO" doc:name="3"/>
</sub-flow>
```

Stack trace:

```
    INFO  2014-01-22 12:30:21,999 [[bass2msp].msp2bassGettingContent.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Not null: IR_1389972193818
INFO  2014-01-22 12:30:22,252 [[bass2msp].msp2bassGettingContent.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Payload: SOME XML CONTENT
INFO  2014-01-22 12:30:22,301 [[bass2msp].msp2bassGettingContent.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: 3
WARN  2014-01-22 12:17:56,335 [[bass2msp].msp2bassGettingContent.stage1.04] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Interceptor for {http://support.cxf.module.mule.org/}ProxyService#{http://support.cxf.module.mule.org/}invoke has thrown exception, unwinding now
  org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: No namespace on "rootNode" element.
  at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.readVersion(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:109)
  at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:141)
  at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:60)
  at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
  at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:799)
  at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit.dispatchMuleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:280)
  at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit$2.handleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:194)
  at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
  at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:533)
  at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:463)
  at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:375)
  at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.doSendWithClient(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:235)
  at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.process(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:125)
  at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
  at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:95)
  at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
  at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:54)
  at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
  at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:26)
  at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:70)
  at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
  at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:65)
  at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
  at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:106)
  at org.mule.routing.outbound.AbstractMessageSequenceSplitter.processParts(AbstractMessageSequenceSplitter.java:133)
  at org.mule.routing.outbound.AbstractMessageSequenceSplitter.process(AbstractMessageSequenceSplitter.java:63)
  at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
  at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:95)
  at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
  at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:54)
  at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
  at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:26)
  at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:70)
  at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
  at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:65)
  at org.mule.routing.Foreach.process(Foreach.java:95)
  at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
  at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:95)
  at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
  at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
  at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:106)
  at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:55)
  at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:122)
  at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:192)
  at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:185)
  at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:20)
  at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:34)
  at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:18)
  at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:58)
  at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
  at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
  at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:44)
  at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
  at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:52)
  at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:32)
  at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:17)
  at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:113)
  at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:34)
  at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:184)
  at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:43)
  at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:311)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
ERROR 2014-01-22 12:17:56,340 [[bass2msp].msp2bassGettingContent.stage1.04] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : No namespace on "rootNode" element.. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: PostMethod
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. No namespace on "rootNode" element. (org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault)
  org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor:109 (null)
2. No namespace on "rootNode" element.. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: PostMethod (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
  org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor:144 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: No namespace on "rootNode" element.
  at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.readVersion(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:109)
  at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:141)
  at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:60)
  + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

### EDIT.1

I did some more research and I found out that problem is when call to subflow in my loop (for each) end. I have put logger after flow-ref and it printed ok till that error (file at the end of flow is generated but logger is quiet). So, is this known/unknown bug or something? Or do I somehow rewrite collection that is looping here: message.payload so that looper cannot read next value? But then, why logger after flow-ref doesn't get triggered inside loop at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cxf:proxy-client` element is a "two way" element, i.e. it deals with the message both in request and response phases.

The "transform" sub-flow affects the message payload, which was the response from the HTTP endpoint, with an XSL-T. This confuses the `cxf:proxy-client` element when it eventually gets the response back flowing through it.

One potential fix is to ref the sub-flow in an `async` block so whatever payload transformation it will do won't be visible to the calling flow, but this will change the response of "msp2bass".

Another option would consist in putting the `byte-array-to-object-transformer` and `choice` elements in a `response` block above the `cxf:proxy-client`, that way you would affect the response after CFX so it would stop complaining.

Comment: I solved it with async but I think better way would be byte[]>object transformer as it can  cause problems with lot's of result sets. In fact, I already got wrong result when there was a lot of resultsets, especially when I made more time consuming operations. Thank you David!